# How to pass <Br /> element when combine text in XML using python?

Tags: python, xml

I've been trying to combine all text in the content element in XML using python.
I succeeded combining all content text but need to except content which is right below <'Br /> element.
<'Br /> element means Enter in adobe indesign program.
This XML is exported from adobe indesign.

This is example as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
<Story>
    <ParagraphStyleRange>
        <CharacterStyleRange>
            <Content>AAA</Content>
        </CharacterStyleRange>
        <CharacterStyleRange>
            <Content>BBB</Content>
        </CharacterStyleRange>
        <CharacterStyleRange>
            <Br />
            <Content>CCC</Content>
            <Br />
            <Content>DDD</Content>
        </CharacterStyleRange>
        <CharacterStyleRange>
            <Content>EEE</Content>
        </CharacterStyleRange>
        <CharacterStyleRange>
            <Br />
            <Content>FFF</Content>
            <Br />
        </CharacterStyleRange>
    </ParagraphStyleRange>
</Story>
</Root>
```

and it's what i want as follow :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
<Story>
    <ParagraphStyleRange>
        <CharacterStyleRange>
            <Content>AAA</Content>
        </CharacterStyleRange>
        <CharacterStyleRange>
            <Content>AAABBB</Content>
        </CharacterStyleRange>
        <CharacterStyleRange>
            <Br />
            <Content>CCC</Content>
            <Br />
            <Content>DDD</Content>
        </CharacterStyleRange>
        <CharacterStyleRange>
            <Content>DDDEEE</Content>
        </CharacterStyleRange>
        <CharacterStyleRange>
            <Br />
            <Content>FFF</Content>
            <Br />
        </CharacterStyleRange>
    </ParagraphStyleRange>
</Story>
</Root>
```

As you see, i don't want to add content text to next one if there is <'Br /> element right above the content that i want to add.

In detail, the first Content element text is AAA and next one is BBB.
in this case AAA should be attched in front of BBB.

and BBB is not attached in front of CCC because there is <'Br /> element right above CCC Content.

Would you help me how to recognize the <'Br /> element to pass?

this is what i'am doing code so far, but it doesn't work well...

```
tree = ET.parse("C:\\Br_test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for ParagraphStyleRange in root.findall('.//Story/ParagraphStyleRange'):
    CharacterStyleRange_count = len(ParagraphStyleRange.findall('CharacterStyleRange'))
    #print(CharacterStyleRange_count)
    if int(CharacterStyleRange_count) >= 2 :
        try :
            Content_collect = ''
            for CharacterStyleRange in ParagraphStyleRange.findall('CharacterStyleRange'):

                Br_count = len(CharacterStyleRange.findall('Br'))
                print(Br_count)
                if int(Br_count) == 0 :
                    for Content in CharacterStyleRange.findall('Content'):
                        Content_collect += Content.text
                        Content.text = str(Content_collect)
                        print(Content_collect)
                #---- Code to delete Contents that are attached to next one---
                #for CharacterStyleRange in ParagraphStyleRange.findall('CharacterStyleRange')[:-1]:
                 #   for Content in CharacterStyleRange.findall('Content'):
                  #      Content_remove = CharacterStyleRange.remove(Content)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Do you have any say in the design.of the xml flavor? It seems more logical to wrap the special content with a `br` element instead of sandwiching it.

Comment: That xml is from adobe indesign. Br element means Enter in indesign program. that's the reason why it is not going to be attached in front of the next content as well as at the end of before step content. you great.